# Magento 2 formkey validator is not working properly in my custom module, return a 500 page

Tags: magento2, form-key

I have an issue that i can not use formkey Validator in my custom module, the module is working fine for me if i am just echoing some text messages, but if i construct the $formKeyValidator or the $formKey then will just return the 500 page, and the route url is correct for me

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $formKey;
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
    )
    {
        $this->formKeyValidator  = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->formKey           =  $formKey;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        echo 'Hello Magento 2! We will change the world!';
        exit;
    }
}
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Clear generated code from generated folder at root of magento

Answer (score 1):

First all, we don't need `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey`. This class was declared already on `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator`.

Second, try to clear generation code: `generated` or `var/generation` folder.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento root index.php file write below code in after PHP tag start.

> error_reporting(E_ALL); 
>   ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Again reload your page. Now you can show an error of code.